# Failed to pass json to rest endpoint in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

How do I bulk insert a json to mongodb? I know I have to use insertMany (I'm using mongoose) but now I'm stuck at getting the right res.body. I have this in my postman.

[image]

This is my node.js code

```js
router.post('/', (req, res) => {    
    console.log(req.body.songs) // ['akon','im lonely','lady gaga','bad romance']    
}
```

Why it turned into an array? Before the route I have something like this:

```js
// Set body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: How are you passing it into the rest handler?

Comment: bodyparser will parse your request body into array/object, check their document for config it as you want

Comment: @SterlingArcher updated my question, missed the picture.

Comment: @RyanWu yup, but it should not be an array, or it's my postman's mistake?

Comment: looks like postman combined artist and title to a long array, you should try to send it as a JSON (with [{artist:"..", title:"..."}]) to verify your backend works well, then come back to use the `x-www-form-urlencoded` see if there's an issue

Comment: Why don't you try to send data as json string from client side and convert it to object/array on server side (node.js)

Answer (score 0):

It's generally easier to work with JSON for cases like this. Set up Postman like this instead when testing:

[image]

Copy/pasteable:

```
{
    "songs": [
        { "artist": "Xzibit", "title": "X" },
        { "artist": "Lady Gaga", "title": "Million Reasons" },
        { "artist": "Adele", "title": "Hello" }
    ]
}
```

Then create the songs like this:

```
Songs
  .create(req.body.songs, (err, songs) => {
    let response = {};

    if (err) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      response.status = HttpStatus.CREATED;
      response.message = songs;
    }

    return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
  });
```

Create takes an array of objects to create.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your keys like this

```
songs[0][artist]
```

instead of this

```
songs[0].artist
```